# Detecting end of input with cin.peek()

Tags: c++11

I am trying to do extraction operator overload that looks at each digit input from user and stores them into an array. Currently, the while loop I am using is not detecting the end of the input stream and the program is just continuously running.

I have tried running a while loop with the logic:

while (cin.peek() != EOF || cin.peek() == '\n')
{
... //read in user input
}

The input is coming from the terminal not a file.

Comment: `cin.peek() == '\n'` part is redundant: whenever `cin.peek() == '\n'` is true, then `cin.peek() != EOF` is clearly also true. To simulate end-of-file on an interactive terminal, you usually need to press a shell-specific keyboard combination, commonly Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+D

Comment: What would I need to change if I wanted the input to end when the user pressed enter?

Comment: Any reason not to use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.